# update Rails HTLM table, using ajax, vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to find the answer but I can only find using jquery, but in my case, I can't use it.

How can I update my partial without reloading my page?

I have this page new.html.erb, that contains a button everytime that I click on this button, it calls my function in javascript.

And its also rendering my table that shows the data that I've saved

// new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h1 id="countdown">10</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="saveMyGame()">Save play</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div id="plays"><%= render 'table' %></div>
```

//_table.html.erb

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Tick</td>
    <th scope="col">Index of image in the array</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% Play.all.each do |play| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= play.current_time %></td>
      <td><%= play.image_url %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

// savegame.js.erb

```
function saveMyGame() {

    var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', '/plays/save_my_play');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.responseText !== countdown) {
            alert('Something went wrong.  Countdown is now ' + countdownt);
        }
        else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(encodeURI('countdown=' + countdown));

}
```

In my controller I can get the data and save my model

//plays_controller.rb

```
class PlaysController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def index
    @plays = Play.all

  end

  def create
    @play = Play.new(post_params)
    if @play.save
      render :new
    end
  end


  def new
    @play = Play.new
    @plays = Play.all

  end


  def save_my_play

    # create an array with all the images selected
    @game = Game.last
    array_images = Array.new()
    @game.images.each do |image|

      array_images.push(url_for(image))

    end

    # get the countdown from ajax request
    countdown = params[:countdown]

    # save the model Play
    play = Play.new
    play.current_time = countdown
    play.image_url = array_images.index(array_images.sample)
    play.save

    @plays = Play.all

  end


  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:play).permit(:current_time, :image_url)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following file:

// `savegame.js` (you can remove `.erb` extension)

```
function saveMyGame() {
    var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', '/plays/save_my_play');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      console.log(this.responseText);
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          document.getElementById("plays").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    auth_token = document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content;
    xhr.send(encodeURI('countdown=' + countdown + '&authenticity_token=' + auth_token));

}
```

Create the following view:

// `app/views/plays/save_my_play.js.erb`

```
<%= render 'table' %>
```

### Explaination

The javascript function will make an AJAX call to `plays/save_my_play` when the button is pressed.

After processing the controller method the server will render the view `app/views/plays/save_my_play.js.erb` which will render the table partial.

The javascript function `saveMyGame` will update your `#plays` with the response received from the server.

Comment: the OP can't use jquery

Comment: You can use vanilla JS like `document.getElementById("plays").innerHTML`

Comment: I can't use jquery

Comment: @BrunoLopesBacelar updated the answer to use vanilla javascript

Comment: I don't know if I did right but it didn't work. @KartikeyTanna

Comment: Can you update savegame.js.erb with how you implemented it.

Comment: @KartikeyTanna this _( document.getElementById("plays").innerHTML("<%= escape_javascript(render 'table') %>") )_  can't be under savegame.js.erb, because this file is under assets/javascript and it doesn't render my partial

Comment: It does not render the partial directly. But when you click the button it the file makes an AJAX call, uploads your data and renders the partial again in JS and that new output is replaced with your old output. That is how your page is changed without reload. Does your AJAX call works fine? Do you get the updated data back in the response?

Comment: I'm getting this error: undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007fb0c6a98868>:0x007fb0c4f827b8> @KartikeyTanna

Comment: @BrunoLopesBacelar yes you are right. The `render` will not work from inside `assets`. I have changed my answer. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://learnetto.com/blog/how-to-make-ajax-calls-in-rails-5-1-with-or-without-jquery

Basically Rails 5.1 now have good support of ajax in ujs library

Comment: I can't use JQuery

Comment: Update the answer.